# How do I activate a specific workbook and a specific sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

How do I activate my Other workbook from the Current workbook? I have a current workbook with dumb.xls and The other workbook name as Tire.xls.I have opened the Tire.xls from the dumb.xls using `worksbooks.open filename:= "name of the file"`.Its getting open but The problem is Im unable to make it work.

If I say `cells(2,24).value=24` puts these value in the cell of dumb.xls but I want it to be done one Tire.xls.

`activesheet.cells(2,24).value=24` puts these on Tire.xls. But how do i activate the Workbook with the name ? I need to open 3 to 4 excel workbooks And perform the operation? How do I activate the specific workbook

I have found this code on google

```
     activeworkbook.worksheet("sheetname").activate  ' but not working
     windows("sheetname").activate ' people on google suggested not to use
```

Its not getting activated. I dont know how to make it work. Can anyone tell me How do i activate a specific workbook and a specific sheet of the other workbook ?

Example: I have niko.xls and niko_2.xls opened as workbooks from the dumb.xls workbook so totally 3 workbooks and I have to activate the 2nd sheet of niko_2.xls workbook.How do I make it? Can anyone explain me the syntax  with these example? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You do not need to activate the sheet (you'll take a huge performance hit for doing so, actually). Since you are declaring an object for the sheet, when you call the method starting with "wb." you are selecting that object. For example, you can jump in between workbooks without activating anything like here:

```
Sub Test()

Dim wb1 As Excel.Workbook
Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\xxxx\Desktop\test1.xls")
Dim wb2 As Excel.Workbook
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\xxxx\Desktop\test2.xls")

wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value = 24
wb2.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value = 24
wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1).Value = 54

End Sub
```

Comment: Anybody got a clue why the above would be giving me a "Compile error - invalid character" error on copy/paste?

Comment: Not sure. I am using a Japanese keyboard so who knows, maybe the backslash or something has a different character code. Try pasting into a txt file then Excel maybe? I noticed a "'" character under Sub Test() so I removed it just in case that was it.

Answer (score 5):

You have to set a reference to the workbook you're opening. Then you can do anything you want with that workbook by using its reference.

```
Dim wkb As Workbook
Set wkb = Workbooks.Open("Tire.xls") ' open workbook and set reference!

wkb.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
wkb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1).Value = 123
```

Could even set a reference to the sheet, which will make life easier later:

```
Dim wkb As Workbook
Dim sht As Worksheet

Set wkb = Workbooks.Open("Tire.xls")
Set sht = wkb.Sheets("Sheet2")

sht.Activate
sht.Cells(2, 1) = 123
```

Others have pointed out that `.Activate` may be superfluous in your case. You don't strictly need to activate a sheet before editing its cells. But, if that's what you want to do, it does no harm to activate -- except for a small hit to performance which should not be noticeable as long as you do it only once or a few times. However, if you activate many times e.g. in a loop, it will slow things down significantly, so activate should be avoided.

Comment: Activate, like select, takes a huge toll on performance. For example, loop the above procedure 10,000 times and with activate it takes about 8 seconds. Without that one line it only takes 0.375 seconds. Of course results differ by machine.

Comment: I'll admit I was surprised to find out the huge difference in avoiding select and activate. Here is some REF (mentions that activate takes a hit on performance): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff726673.aspx

Comment: Yeah, good point, though if the OP isn't looping then it won't be noticeable. I'll add a remark to that effect in my answer.

Comment: You're right, unless you were using activate a lot, you wouldn't notice the difference (it's still good to know, IMO). Becuase I love exagerated results, I tried looping it 1 million times. Without .activate it took 35 seconds, with it, it took a whopping 13 minutes! :p

Comment: Um, that just multiplied your earlier results by 100, as would be expected!

Comment: Aha! Didn't realize that and boy, I feel kind of silly now when I think about it!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

```
Workbooks("Tire.xls").Activate

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Cells(2,24).value=24
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Wb As Excel.Workbook
Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(file_path)
Wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2,24).Value = 24
Wb.Close
```

To know the sheets name to refer in `Wb.Sheets("sheetname")` you can use the following :

```
Dim sht as Worksheet    
For Each sht In tempWB.Sheets
    Debug.Print sht.Name
Next sht
```

Comment: Sorry BUt Let me know how do i activate a sheet ? your putting some values in it i want to do all sorting and operations in that workbook than close it ? Should i need to always indicate Wb.sheets("sheet1")...... let me know it ?

Answer (score 0):

The code that worked for me is:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheetName").Activate
```

Comment: I tried all the methods mentioned here for selecting a worksheet(switching from one worksheet to another, in fact.) However, I am getting "Application or object defined error". The worksheet exists(I added a code to verify this through a msgbox.) Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Windows("name.xls").Activate
```

Comment: You should explain why your answer is useful more than 2,5 year latter. Did you tested it, in regard of the other answer?