# Excel 2010, VBA From Different Workbook Cannot Return IsEmpty Value

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

The below code should delete a row if Cell(1,2) is empty.  When being run within the workbook which contains the code, it accurately returns the IsEmpty function.  When being run from an ActiveSheet in another workbook, it will not return the IsEmpty function.  Is there a solution for this?

```
Public Sub formatSheet()
Dim test As Boolean
test = IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2))
'Removes header lines
Do Until test = False
    Rows("1:1").Delete
    test = IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2))
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Where did you place this code snippet in the 1st and 2nd Workbooks?

Comment: Try running the code with `test <> False`, i am on ubuntu so cant help you anymore.

Comment: you need to reference the workbook that you want it to run on otherwise ActiveSheet is the current activesheet in the workbook it is running in.

Comment: I intentionally want it to run **on** the current active sheet (the sheet/workbook I'm looking at, does not contain the code to be run).  I want it to run **from** another workbook (the sheet/work I'm not looking at, does contain the code to be run).

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate the workbook and worksheet you want to delete the row from first:

[How do i activate a specific workbook and a specific sheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977807/how-do-i-activate-a-specific-workbook-and-a-specific-sheet)

Hope that link helps!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to activate the spreadsheet you want it to run on, but you do need to refer to the sheet and workbook. To do this without creating objects and associated pointers, try this code:

```
    test = IsEmpty(Workbook("NameOfWorkBookYouWishToCheck").Sheets("NameOfSheetYouWishToCheck").Cells(1, 2))
```