# How to reference an opened not active workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to reference from code in an active workbook to another workbook,
I don't want to type path like that workbooks("path") , this reference should be flexible, is there something like array of already opened workbooks ?

Comment: Could this give you some idea? http://xlvba.fr.yuku.com/topic/135/List-all-open-workbooks#.VZT9pfmqqko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign an open workbook to a variable without providing the full path. You can then use the set object variable to perform any actions you wish.

```
Sub set_wb()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks("test_wb.xlsb")
    wb.Activate
End Sub
```

You can also iterate through each open workbook using `for each`

```
Sub wb_names()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    For Each wb In Workbooks
        Debug.Print wb.Name
    Next wb
End Sub
```

Similarly, you can use `for` to iterate through each workbook using their index (the index is dependant on which order workbooks were opened).

```
Sub wb_index()
    Dim i As Byte
    For i = 1 To Workbooks.Count
        Debug.Print Workbooks(i).Name
    Next i
End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6978827/4243498).

To reference an already open workbook, you can use

```
Workbooks("book_name.xlsx")
```

You can also iterate through the collection

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To Workbooks.Count
    MsgBox Workbooks(i).Name
Next i
```