# Selecting worksheet: Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range

Tags: excel, vba

I am extremely new to Excel VBA.

My goal is to create a command button to open a password protected workbook, automatically copy data from selected cells within specific worksheets and paste into the unprotected workbook. The data also needs to be placed in the next empty row as the data in the protected workbook changes daily.

I have not been able to get around a range error at

```
Worksheets("Sheet14").Select
xDate = Range("L2")
```

> Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Workbooks.Open Filename:="P:\source.xlsx", Password:="password"
Dim xDate As String
Dim ACD As String
Dim Untouched As String
Dim DailyAct As String
Dim SchedAdherence As String
Dim Status As String
Worksheets("Sheet14").Select
xDate = Range("L2")
Worksheets("Sheet5").Select
ACD = Range("C4")
Worksheets("Sheet5").Select
DailyAct = Range("E4")
Worksheets("Sheet5").Select
SchedAdherence = Range("F4")
Worksheets("Sheet7").Select
Status = Range("B5")

Set TrackingReport = Workbooks("C:\Destination"): TrackingReport.Activate

Worksheets("Sheet2").Select
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B1").Select
RowCount = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B1").CurrentRegion.Row.Count
With Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B1")
.Offset(RowCount, 0) = xDate
.Offset(RowCount, 1) = ACD
.Offset(RowCount, 2) = DailyAct
.Offset(RowCount, 3) = SchedAdherence
.Offset(RowCount, 4) = Status
End With
TrackingReport.Save
Set DailyPerformance = Workbooks.Open("P:\source.xlsx",Password:="password")
DailyPerformance.Close
End Sub
```

Source Data
[image: Source Data]

Destination Data
[image: Destination Data]

Comment: what error is it that you are getting and on which line

Comment: amy oakes - Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range. Not sure how to identify which line it occurring on as it isn't highlighting any of the code.

Comment: To debug press the F8 Key and this will let you step through youre code and the error message will pop up when you get to the line of code that isnt working

Comment: Looks like it is popping up at
    Worksheets("Sheet14").Select
    xDate = Range("L2")

Comment: Take a look at this might help http://codevba.com/excel/set_workbook.htm#.WalezrKGOUk

Comment: That would suggest you haven't got a worksheet called "Sheet14" ?

Comment: I have corrected the names and now the same Run-Time Error is popping up at         Set TrackingReport = Workbooks

Comment: When you get to that point in the code are you wanting to open 'Tracking Report' or just refer to it to run the rest of the code on?

Comment: Refer to it for the rest of the code and then once the copy has been completed, close out the password protected book.

Comment: In that case i would open it here like you have done previously here `Workbooks.Open Filename:="P:\source.xlsx"` youre going to come across another error though as you have set `RowCount` with out declaring it. I would normaly declare it as variant as it is going to change each time the use something like this to find the last row `Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: I am not following. Do you mind showing me where these changes would take place in the code provided? Also, would I open the workbook if it is already open or would I need to select it in some other way?

Comment: Apolgies i thought your button was in a completely different work book: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977807/how-do-i-activate-a-specific-workbook-and-a-specific-sheet) on how to set and select workbooks to see if you can build it in your self. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="P:\source.xlsx", Password:="password"
    Dim xDate As String
    Dim ACD As String
    Dim Untouched As String
    Dim DailyAct As String
    Dim SchedAdherence As String
    Dim Status As String
    Worksheets("Sheet14").Select ' Change this sheet name
    xDate = Range("L2")
    Worksheets("Sheet5").Select
    ACD = Range("C4")
    Worksheets("Sheet5").Select
    DailyAct = Range("E4")
    Worksheets("Sheet5").Select
    SchedAdherence = Range("F4")
    Worksheets("Sheet7").Select
    Status = Range("B5")

    Set TrackingReport = Workbooks("C:\Destination"): TrackingReport.Activate ' `CHANGE THIS TO Workbooks.Open Filename:="P:\TrackingReport.xlsx" (or where ever it is saved)` 

    Worksheets("Sheet2").Select
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B1").Select
    RowCount = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B1").CurrentRegion.Row.Count ' Here im assuming you are find the last row you to know where to paste from if so i would use something like this instead

    Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' This looks at your selected column in this case columns 1. Hoowver you would need to ensure that is is a column that is always filled in 

    With Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B1")
    .Offset(RowCount, 0) = xDate
    .Offset(RowCount, 1) = ACD
    .Offset(RowCount, 2) = DailyAct
    .Offset(RowCount, 3) = SchedAdherence
    .Offset(RowCount, 4) = Status
    End With
    TrackingReport.Save
    Set DailyPerformance = Workbooks.Open("P:\source.xlsx",Password:="password")
    DailyPerformance.Close
    End Sub
```

In a test workbook i created this worked:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim xDate As String
Dim ACD As String
Dim Untouched As String
Dim DailyAct As String
Dim SchedAdherence As String
Dim Status As String
Dim TrackingReport As Excel.Workbook
Dim DailyPerformance As Excel.Workbook



Set DailyPerformance = Workbooks.Open("P:\source.xlsx", Password:="password")

'Change you sheet names here
Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
xDate = Range("V2").Value
Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
ACD = Range("C4").Value
Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
DailyAct = Range("E4").Value
Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
SchedAdherence = Range("F4").Value
Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
Status = Range("B5").Value

Set TrackingReport = Workbooks.Open("YourPathHere")

Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Select
RowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1")
.Offset(RowCount, 0) = xDate
.Offset(RowCount, 1) = ACD
.Offset(RowCount, 2) = DailyAct
.Offset(RowCount, 3) = SchedAdherence
.Offset(RowCount, 4) = Status
End With
TrackingReport.Save


DailyPerformance.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: I am needing it to only copy those cells and then paste them into the Tracking Report. Please note that the data is being placed into a running table. Will I also need to write coding for it to create another row before pasting the data?

Comment: no you shouldnt need to the row count make sure it goes on to the next empty row.

Comment: Hey Amy. It's not closing DailyPerformance and it's still not pasting the data to my table. My code looks exactly like yours too. No errors are firing either.

Comment: would it be possible to add a sample of your data just because the code works fine on my test workbooks :)

Comment: How would I provide the sample on here?

Comment: add a screenshot to you question :)

Comment: Samples added :)