# Copy the unique items to other sheet and delete the item in the sheet in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a excel vba which compares two sheets ( Interface  , Steps ) . Whenever a unique record is found in the steps . It will be deleted . I wanted to edit the exist code in such manner that instead of deleting the records , it should be copied to new sheet ( Steps2 ) first and delete it next . I am pretty new to VBA , I have included the code below. I don't want to use copy and paste function as it takes long time to execute. I am looking to create with scripting dictionary . Any help me in achieving the result would help me.

```
Option Explicit

Function UpdateOLD() As Long
'     This Sub will do the Following Update
'     Run through all records in OLD
'        if found in Interface  ---> Do nothing
'        if not found in Interface ----> Delete it from Steps.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Rng As Range
Dim WSO As Worksheet
Dim WSN As Worksheet
Dim MaxRowO As Long, MaxRowN As Long, I As Long, J As Long, lDel As Long
Dim sJob As String, sOps As String, sFirstAddress As String
Dim cCell As Range
Dim bNotFound As Boolean


'---> Disable Events
With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

'---> Set Variables
Set WSO = Sheets("Steps")
Set WSN = Sheets("Interface")
MaxRowO = WSO.Range("A" & WSO.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
MaxRowN = WSN.Range("C" & WSN.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
WSO.Range("N2:N" & MaxRowO).ClearContents

'---> Loop thruough all rows in sheet New
For I = 2 To MaxRowO
    bNotFound = False
    sJob = WSO.Cells(I, "B")
    sOps = WSO.Cells(I, "C")
    Set cCell = WSN.Range("D6:D" & MaxRowN).Find(what:=sJob, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not cCell Is Nothing Then
        bNotFound = True
        sFirstAddress = cCell.Address
        Do
            '---> Check to See if Ops if found for that Job
            If WSN.Cells(cCell.Row, "E") = sOps Then
                bNotFound = False
                Exit Do
            End If
            Set cCell = WSN.Range("D6:D" & MaxRowN).FindNext(cCell)
        Loop While Not cCell Is Nothing And cCell.Address <> sFirstAddress
    Else
        bNotFound = True
    End If

    '---> Del Record from OLD if Not Found
    If bNotFound Then
        If Rng Is Nothing Then
        Set Rng = WSO.Range("A" & I)
        Else
        Set Rng = Union(Rng, WSO.Range("A" & I))
        lDel = lDel + 1
        End If
    End If
Next I

If Not Rng Is Nothing Then Rng.EntireRow.Delete

'---> Enable Events
With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

UpdateOLD = lDel

End Function
```

Comment: You mention wanting a `dictionary`, but i see nothing in your code where you have tried to use a dictionary.  Would you please update to show your efforts in that regard?  Note that StackOverflow generally helps with *specific* coding issues that have *objective* answers.

Comment: Alternative: Use a helper column with eg `=COUNTIF(A:A, A1)` then filter on that column. Everything `>1` is a duplicate, everything `=1` is unique. If multiple criteria at once are needed check `=COUNTIFS()`. • For VBA have a look at [WorksheetFunction.CountIf method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.countif). Use it to loop throug data and union.

Comment: `Match()` would help find existing item and outputs a row number which would provide easier deletion.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your asking if you can move values from one worksheet to another?

See:
[How do i activate a specific workbook and a specific sheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977807/how-do-i-activate-a-specific-workbook-and-a-specific-sheet)

- Keep a counter to record which row is open (for the next value)
- If its an individual then:

```
wb1.Sheets("SourceSheet").Cells(row, columnNumber).Value = wb1.Sheets("OutputSheet").Cells(counter, columnNumber).Value
```